# Is it meaningful to store the result of a trigonometric function call?

Tags: c++, compilation, trigonometry, compiler-optimization, std

Suppose I was writing an implementation of a `rotate()` method of a `vector2D` library.

```
vector2D rotate(const vector2D vector, const vector2D origin, float radians)
{
    // Implementation details
    return {x, y};
}
```

I could store the result of trigonometric function calls in variables, so I don't have to call them multiple times:

```
float sr = sin(radians);
float cr = cos(radians);
float x = origin.x + (
    (vector.x - origin.x) * cr - (vector.y - origin.y) * sr
);
float y = origin.y + (
    (vector.x - origin.x) * sr + (vector.y - origin.y) * cr
);
```

Or I could simply write what I mean

```
float x = origin.x + (
    (vector.x - origin.x) * cos(radians) - (vector.y - origin.y) * sin(radians)
);
float y = origin.y + (
    (vector.x - origin.x) * sin(radians) + (vector.y - origin.y) * cos(radians)
);
```

- What are pros and cons for each of these cases?
- Does compiler optimize the overhead in the second example away? Or is the overhead of calling trig functions multiple times insignificant even in case of a `vector2D` library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version is likely the code the compiler would generate if it optimizes the second version.

Some compilers might know that `sin` and `cos` are pure functions that always return the same value for a specific argument. But the language standard says nothing about that, so we cannot be sure.

Also, before trying local optimizations like this you might ask yourself if this function is called often enough to be a bottleneck in the application. If not, perhaps the exact speed difference will not be noticed.

The gcc compiler maps sin and cos to [`__builtin_sin` and `__builtin_cos`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) so it has additional knowledge of these functions, but I don't know if the optimizer takes any advantage of that.

Comment: The gcc compiler maps sin and cos to [`__builtin_sin` and `__builtin_cos`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) so it has additional knowledge of these functions, but I don't know if the optimizer takes any advantage of that.

Comment: GCC not only saves result of sin/cos, but actually calculates [both at the same time](http://goo.gl/fkSLcf). Clang is not that sharp, sadly. Another thing to consider: if you do calculations in doubles, much less code would be generated.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot What do you mean by 'calculations in doubles'? "Doubles" as the duplicated code in the second example?

Comment: @Dundee as in `double` instead of `float`. I know that there are many valid uses for floats (GPU calculations or SIMD instructons come to mind), and without knowing your situation it is impossible to determine if it worth to change datatype, hence "consider".

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: Actually, the code I am writing is entirely templated, so the data types are not really a concern of mine. (I just removed it for the clarity of the question) But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You could also define variables for `vector.x - origin.x` and `vector.y - origin.y`. As already has been stated, this is not so much a matter of performance because the compiler would implement these optimizations anyway, but a matter of code readability.

If you create these additional variables, you should also declare them as `const` because you are not intending to change their values.

There are different opinions on using these "redundant" variables. I personally would use them if I can find a meaningful name for them.

Comment: @Dundee: Not sure, you have been asking for pros and cons and I think that I have added some additional aspects to the existing answer.